# pandas select next column header while in loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to access the next column header while in a loop going through the columns of a pandas dataframe.

```
for cols in data.columns:
    if data.columns.get_loc(cols) < len(data.columns):  # skip last column of data
        count = data.groupby([cols, cols+1]).size()  # create new df and how many times the two columns occur
```

However `cols+1` gives me an error. This is because `cols` returns the header name, so you can't +1 a string, but what would be the best way to get the next column header over while in a loop like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate on columns

```
for col_index, cols in enumerate(data.columns):
    if col_index+1 < len(data.columns):  # skip last column of data
        count = data.groupby([cols,data.columns[col_index+1]]).size()  # create new df and how many times the two columns occur
```

Comment: are you sure you won't get an `IndexError`?

Answer (score 1):

```
for col_idx in range(len(data.columns)-1):
    if data.columns.get_loc(data.columns[col_idx]) < len(data.columns): 
        count = data.groupby([col_idx, col_idx+1]).size()
```